# Award points if a specific custom taxonomy is selected - Cubepoints

Tags: plugins, php, custom-taxonomy, cubepoints

I run a multiple author platform where [Cubepoints](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cubepoints/) is a major part of its point and ranking system.

I have added a [custom category taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) called `highlight` and it contains two items: `featured` and `spotlight`.

Whenever an excellent post is submitted, an editor check it as `featured` or `spotlight` - both of which gives the article a lot of exposure on the site. If the users article is highlighted, they receives a custom amount of extra points. The problem is that the editors are forced to add these points manually by browsing to Cubepoints / Add Points.

This is an exhausting process to do manually. **How can I make this work automatically**? This means that if `featured` is checked for the custom taxonomy (highlight), then the user gets 30 points with the description "Your article has been featured", and if `spotlight` is selected, they receive 50 points with a similar form of description.

Unfortunately, the Cubepoints API documentation is noneexistent, however, I good [tutorial](http://efieldguide.com/using-the-cubepoints-plugin-api/) was recently written by a user.

Comment: You want to add points to Cubepoints? Does Cubepoints have an API?

Comment: @s_ha_dum The API documentation is very poor I'm afraid. However, some users have managed to write various tutorials such as this one: http://efieldguide.com/using-the-cubepoints-plugin-api/

Comment: Your link returns a 403

Comment: It works perfectly fine here. Many your IP is blocked on their server by some reason, try accessing it through anon proxy.

Comment: Update: You are right, upon refreshing the page, it gives a 403. Luckly I saved the page and uploaded it here: http://bogsorken.com/wpse/cubepoints/ Mind the styling issues... I am sure that the original site has some very random server issues atm.

Answer (score 0):

The bulk of your question seems to me to be about Cubepoint's API, with is off topic here. The WordPress part would be this:

1. I am not sure how your system works, or is supposed too work, but it sounds like you want to hook into `save_post`, but I am guessing about that part. Maybe you are doing this with AJAX or with something on the front end.
2. Check for your fields
3. Use [`WP_HTTP`](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) to submit to Codepoint's API, which doesn't look that difficult to deal with-- [cp_api=user/login/billly/points/add/500 (or cp_api=user/id/5/points/add/500)](http://bogsorken.com/wpse/cubepoints/)
   It looks like you want [`wp_remote_get`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get) for that

It should look something like:

```
function mypoints($oost_id) {
    // check to see if you need to update your points
    // I don't know what all the parameters for that are but
    if ( $need_to_update_points === true) {
        $apiresponse = wp_remote_get("http://www.your-site.com/?cp_api_key=abc123&cp_api=user/login/billy/points/add/25/log/custom/Happy+Birthday!");
        // check api response for sanity
    }

}
add_action('save_post','mypoints');
```

I am not sure why the example in your tutorial is submitting to "your-site.com". Maybe I didn't read part of that carefully enough. :) That is the idea though.

Comment: Yes indeed, I want to hook into `save_posts`. I did not understand your third point. Is there any chance that you could kindly provide a code example that might guide me to the right direction?